# Are "kif kef" bars chalav Yisroel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Specifically, I am looking at Israeli Kif Kef bars - the ones sold in the States. Presumably they are identical to the ones from Israel. See picture. The hechture is Bedatz.  [image]

Comment: Which "Bedatz"? There are lots of them

Comment: "Presumably they are identical to the ones from Israel" - That's not a safe assumption. They may have identical packaging, but frequently, Israeli products manufactured for export may be processed differently. If I may ask, how do you know these are "Chalav Yisra'el" in Israel? I know that sounds strange, but a few of my friends in Israel told me that even in Israel they need a "chalav Yisra'el" marking for people that are particular.

Comment: @DanF Every dairy product approved by the Israeli Chief Rabbinate can be assumed to be Chalav Yisrael. In fact, the rabbinate will not approve products containing actual non-supervised milk. (In this regard they are more stringent than the OU.) They do approve products containing non-Chalav Yisrael milk **powder** or butter, but the packaging will always state clearly if the product contains either of these ingredients.

Comment: @DanF This is why (at least historically) the rabbinate would not approve the sale of Haagen Dazs ice cream in Israel. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.joyofkosher.com/.amp/blogs/haagen-dasz-in-israel-no-longer-kosher/

Comment: Just flip it and read the label.

Comment: Be aware that some of those bars have just the OU printed on them and others have the Badatz Eidat Hachareidit on them as well.

Comment: @Al Berko, I flipped the label - it didn’t mention it.

Comment: Love it! Kif Kaf looks suspiciously like Kit Kat bars.

Comment: The one in the picture is Badatz Eda Chareidit in Jerusalem which only certifies *halav Israel* products. I think it is correct that all Kif Kef are produced in Israel and it is correct they are exactly like Kit Kat

Answer (score 3):

I checked a few shopping sites. It seems that for some reason, all the U.S.-based on-line shopping sites sell the Hebrew packaged bag. That one clearly says that it is Chalav Yisra'el. [This site](https://www.ohnuts.com/buy.cfm/bulk-chocolate/dark-milk-bars/elite/mini-kif-kef-22ct-bag) shows the Hebrew text package, says the product is Chalav Yisra'el, and says that the text on the package may be in English. I assume that ENglish text doesn't affect the Chalav Yisra'el status.

Additionally, [this site](https://www.aviglatt.com/elite-chocolates-candy) sells other Elite chocolate bars. They have English packaging and the products are all Chalav Yisra'el.

Just my own deduction - I can't quite see that Elite would make all the other chocolates Chalav Yisra'el but not Kif Kef. And, as stated, it looks like the Kif Kef sold in the states is the exact one sold in Israel, as I don't see any of these sites selling an English-text bag.

Check with a rav, a store mashgiach or call Elite or even OU (seems they certify the chocolate bars) to be sure.